# DBD::mysql::st execute failed: MySQL server has gone away at

Tags: mysql, perl

I want to insert data from a fifo pipe into a mysql table

my script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#Script to read data out of a named pipe and write to MySQL database.

$| = 1;

use strict;
use DBI();

my $filename;
my $inputline;
my $linenumber;
my @arr;
$filename = "./SEC_fifo";
open(FIFO, "+< $filename") or die "FIFO error on $filename $!";
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=ecdb;host=localhost",
        "user", "[pwd]",
        {'RaiseError' => 1});
while (<FIFO>)
{
  $inputline = $_;
   @arr = split(/,/,$inputline);

  # Quit read loop when requested.
  last if($inputline =~ /quit/i);

  chop $inputline;
  $linenumber++;
  print "Got: [$inputline], ";
  my $sql="";
  my $sth="";
  my @row;
  print  "output.\n".$arr[0],$arr[1],$arr[2],$arr[3],$arr[4],$arr[5],$arr[6],$arr[7],$arr[8],$arr[9],$arr[10],$arr[11],$arr[12],$arr[13]."\n";
# perl trim function - remove leading and trailing whitespace
  my $str = $arr[6] ;
  $str =~ s/^\s+//; 
  $str =~ s/\s+$//;

 if($str ne 'Normal')
  { 
     print "arr[6]=".$arr[6]."\n";
    $sql = "select Hid from Devices where hostname = '$arr[2]'";
    print $sql."\n";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute || die "Could not execute SQL statement ... maybe invalid? \n\n $sql   
   \n";
   @row=$sth->fetchrow_array;
   my $hid1=@row[0];
   $sql = "select Hid from Devices where hostname = '$arr[3]'";
   $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
   $sth->execute || die "Could not execute SQL statement ... maybe invalid? \n\n $sql \n";
   @row=$sth->fetchrow_array;
   my $hid2=@row[0];
   $sql = "select Eid from Event where Eventname = '$arr[8]' and severity = '$arr[9]' and Trapoid='$arr[10]'";
   print "sql=".$sql."\n";
   $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
   $sth->execute || die "Could not execute SQL statement ... maybe invalid? \n\n $sql \n";
   @row=$sth->fetchrow_array;
   my $eid1=@row[0];
   #print "eid1=".@row[0]."\n";
   $sql = "select Eid from Event where Eventname = '$arr[11]' and severity = '$arr[12]' and Trapoid='$arr[13]'";
   #print "sql=".$sql."\n";
   $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
   $sth->execute || die "Could not execute SQL statement ... maybe invalid? \n\n $sql \n";
   @row=$sth->fetchrow_array;
   my $eid2=@row[0];
   print "eid1=".$eid1."\n";
   print "eid2=".@row[0]."\n";
   $sql = "insert into secresult (Hid_1,Hid_2,interface_1,interface_2,ifindex_1,ifindex_2,Eid_1,Eid_2,start_time_1,start_time_2,effect_range,description) values ($hid1,$hid2,'$arr[4]','$arr[5]',$arr[6],$arr[7],$eid1,$eid2,'$arr[0]','$arr[1]','$arr[14]','$arr[15]')";
   print $sql."\n";
   $dbh->do($sql);
   print "inserted it.\n";

 }
 else
{  
  $sql = "select Hid from Devices where hostname = '$arr[1]'";
  $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute || die "Could not execute SQL statement ... maybe invalid? \n\n $sql \n";
  @row=$sth->fetchrow_array;
  my $hid=@row[0];

  $sql = "select Eid from Event where trapoid = '$arr[0]' and severity != 'Normal'";
  #print "sql=".$sql."\n";
  $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute || die "Could not execute SQL statement ... maybe invalid? \n\n $sql \n";
  @row=$sth->fetchrow_array;
  my $eid=@row[0];

  $sql = "select id from (SELECT * FROM secresult WHERE end_time_1 ='' and Hid_1=$hid and interface_1 ='$arr[4]' and ifindex_1=$arr[5] ORDER BY start_time_1 DESC LIMIT 1) result where result.eid_1 = $eid";
  print "sql=".$sql."\n";
  $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute || die "Could not execute SQL statement ... maybe invalid? \n\n $sql \n";
  @row=$sth->fetchrow_array;
  my $id=@row[0];
  if($id !="")
   {
     $sql = "update secresult set end_time_1 = '$arr[2]' where id = '$id'";
     print $sql."\n";
     $dbh->do($sql);
     print "updated it.\n";
  }
   else 
   {
      $sql = "select id from (SELECT * FROM secresult WHERE end_time_2 ='' and Hid_1=$hid and interface_2 ='$arr[4]' and ifindex_2=$arr[5] ORDER BY start_time_2 DESC LIMIT 1) result where result.eid_2 = $eid";
    print "sql=".$sql."\n";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute || die "Could not execute SQL statement ... maybe invalid? \n\n $sql \n";
    @row=$sth->fetchrow_array;
    $id=@row[0];
    $sql = "update secresult set end_time_2 = '$arr[2]' where id = '$id'";
    print $sql."\n";
    $dbh->do($sql);
    print "updated it.\n";

   }

 }

 }

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM secresult"); $sth->execute(); while (my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
print "Found a row: id = $ref->{'id'}, line = $ref->{'textline'}\n"; }

  $sth->finish();

 $dbh->disconnect();

 exit;
```

i can insert into to database by the script,but when i execute the script to listening , after few minute get data from fifo ,the script will be shown the error message "DBD::mysql::st execute failed: MySQL server has gone away at ./Db_code.pl line 66,  line 5"

the line 66 is " $sth->execute || die "Could not execute SQL statement ... maybe invalid? \n\n $sql \n";"

Comment: What did google tell you?

Comment: Looks like the server is not reachable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just make sure dbh is still connected (ping) before any DB operations and reconnect (or clone)

```
while (<FIFO>)
{
    if ( ! $dbh->ping ) {
        $dbh = $dbh->clone() or die "cannot connect to db";
    }

...

} #end FIFO
```

See also http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=497849

Comment: thank you!! this took me more than 2 hours in troubleshooting before using your solution

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative you can use the mysql auto reconnect feature.

```
$dbh->{mysql_auto_reconnect} = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The main reason that could result in this error is that the client is not able to reach the server for some reason. It can occurs after the server has timed out and closed the connection.

In such case you have to gather some statistic to check if your MySQL server is slow or not and to check your SQL statement.

Here you can refer to the error documentation from official Mysql docs: [MySQL Server has gone away](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html).

Comment: i am sure that client can connect to server

Comment: because for database security, i can't modify the database wait_time,have other way to modify the script that can restartup when the connect is close ? can i modify the script to run like a deamon ?add loop?

Comment: As far as I know you can set the `mysql-auto-reconnect` flag on but I assume this is a risky one when deadlocks may occur. Here you can refer to a good thred about your issue http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=317168.